# MapBox GL JS - set set polygon Z-ordering on a layer

Tags: mapbox

I would like to set the Z-ordering of the polygons on my MapBox GL JS vectortile layer with only one vector tile source. There is a "category" attribute with values: 1 and 2. Polygons with category 2 should be on the top.

This is the definiton of my layer:

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'testLayer',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': 'testSource','source-layer': 'polygons',
      "paint": {
'fill-color':   {    "property": "cat",
          "type": "categorical",
          "stops": [
            [1, "#8dd3c7"],
            [2, "#ffffb3"]
          ]}
    }
});
```

How can I set Z ordering?

I'vew find this: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/optimize-map-label-placement/

Order of features inside layers
For each layer in your style, you must specify a source. For vector sources, you must also specify a source layer for each style layer. The draw order of features inside a single vector tileset source layer can be specified in two ways:
At runtime with symbol-sort-key: If you don't have control over the data at the time of tileset creation, you can influence the draw order of features at runtime using symbol-sort-key.

How to use it? I don't know the syntax and I didn't find any examples.

UPDATE: I tried with symbol-sort-key, but I got this error: "unknown property "symbol-sort-key""

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'testLayer',
  'type': 'fill',
  'source': 'testSource','source-layer': 'polygons',
  'layout': {"symbol-sort-key": ["to-number", ["get", "cat"]]},
      "paint": {
'fill-color':   {    "property": "cat",
          "type": "categorical",
          "stops": [
            [1, "#8dd3c7"],
            [2, "#ffffb3"]
          ]}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know layers in mapbox can not be specified in a numeric value of z-index. but there is moveLayer function. moveLayer, moves a layer to a different z-position.

```
map.moveLayer('polygon', 'polygon2');
```

Move a layer with ID 'polygon' before the layer with ID 'polygon2'. The `polygon` layer will appear beneath the `polygon2` layer on the map.

another way:

I think you can try to add fill-sort-key to your layers seperately something like this:

```
"fill-sort-key": ["to-number", ["get", "priority"]],
```

Note: [credits to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103558/7688423)

Comment: What about the fill-sort-key? https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-fill-fill-sort-key "Sorts features in ascending order based on this value. Features with a higher sort key will appear above features with a lower sort key." Unfortunately I don't know how to use it and I didn't find any example.

Comment: @zsoooc updated my answer, maybe you can try or see the the answer I linked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, unfortunately I get this error: "unknown property "symbol-sort-key"" I updated my question with the new code. What do you think?

Comment: but your layer type is "fill", you should use fill-sort-key. if your type is line : line-sort-key, etc...